# Java collection methods for union, Intersection and set difference

Tags: java

I have written a program with 2 different collections of numbers and I was wondering how would I get the union, intersection and set difference from these two collections? I know that BitSet has methods for it but those doesn't work here.

```
public class Collections {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // 1. Collection
    Set<Integer> grp1 = new HashSet<Integer>();

    grp1.add(1);
    grp1.add(2);
    grp1.add(3);
    grp1.add(4);
    grp1.add(5);

    // printing 1. collection
    System.out.println("1. collection: ");
    Iterator<Integer> i = grp1.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        int numbers1 = i.next();
        System.out.print(numbers1 + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();   

    // 2. collection
    Set<Integer> grp2 = new HashSet<Integer>();

    grp2.add(8);
    grp2.add(7);
    grp2.add(6);
    grp2.add(5);
    grp2.add(4);

    // printing 2. collection
    System.out.println("2. collection: ");
    Iterator<Integer> y = grp2.iterator();
    while(y.hasNext()) {
        int numbers2 = y.next();
        System.out.print(numbers2 + " ");

    // Union


    // Intersection


    // Difference

         }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 12):

Union:

```
Set<Integer> union = new HashSet<>(grp1);
union.addAll(grp2);
```

Intersection:

```
Set<Integer> intersection = new HashSet<>(grp1);
intersection.retainAll(grp2);
```

Difference:

```
Set<Integer> diff = new HashSet<>(grp1);
diff.removeAll(grp2);
```

Comment: I wish it worked that way, but all of those operations are actually destructive, i.e. they work in-place, on the existing collection, and they all return boolean. Your code does unfortunately not compile. I wish it did.

Comment: I already did try those but none of them work in Eclipse:'' Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to Set<Integer>''. EDIT: like Sean said they return boolean values.

Comment: Ah true!! I forgot about the signatures! Too much scala those days :)

Answer (score 7):

[**Guava**](https://github.com/google/guava) has these operations in it's [**`Sets`**](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html) class.

```
Set<Integer> union = Sets.union(set1, set2);
Set<Integer> intersection = Sets.intersection(set1, set2);
Set<Integer> difference = Sets.difference(set1, set2);
```

All of these return unmodifiable views, backed by the original Sets.

See [**Guava Explained** -> **Collection Utilities** -> **Sets**](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#sets)